# Knot Traces and Trace Lemma

Tags: knot-theory, 4-manifolds

I'm currently reading the paper by Miller and Piccirillo titled [Knot Traces and Concordance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03974). I have some confusion about the proof of theorem 1.8. In particular the 'if' direction.

I'll restate some of the definitions of objects they use. The trace $X_K$ of a knot $K$ is defined as the union of a 4-ball with a 2 handle attached along $K$. Then the 'if' statement claims that a smooth embedding of $X_K$ into $S^4$ means that $K$ is smooth slice, i.e., bounds a smooth disc in $B^4$.

Consider the composition of the inclusion of the core of the 2 handle with the smooth embedding from the hypothesis: $D^2 \rightarrow X_K \rightarrow S^4$

Then this defines a smooth disc with  boundary $K$ in $S^4$ and thus $B^4$ since the image is not surjective.

I was wondering what is the problem with this approach? Is the 2 core not necessarily smoothly embedded?

The authors choose to consider a map from $S^2 \rightarrow X_K \rightarrow S^4$ and restrict it to a disc. Is this choice deliberate in order to avoid some problems with the argument above?

Thanks forgive my ignorance if I am asking something stupid. (Below is an excerpt from the paper.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the existence of a smooth, nonsurjective embedding $f : X \hookrightarrow S^4$ implies the existence of a smooth embedding $g : X \hookrightarrow B^4$. The way that I would prove this implication is to choose a point $p$ not in the image of an embedding, choose a smooth tiny round 4-ball $B(p,\epsilon)$ disjoint from the image of that embedding, and then choose a diffeomorphism $h : S^4 \setminus B(p,\epsilon) \to B^4$, and define $g = h \circ f$.

However, the smooth slice hypothesis is different, it requires the existence of a smooth embedding $D^2 \hookrightarrow B^4$ which, when restricted to $S^1 = \partial D^2$, has image equal to $K$. The embedding $g : X \to B^4$ above can certainly be restricted to $D^2$ to give an embedding $g : D^2 \to B^4$, but when that is further restricted to $S^1$, its image is some random circle in the interior of $B^4$ that has nothing to do with the given knot $K$.

The point here is that when $f : X \hookrightarrow S^4$ is given as above, the *exterior* of $f(B^4)$ in $S^4$ is diffeomorphic to $B^4$. Composing $f$ with that diffeomorphism, and then restricting to $D^2$, one gets a smooth embedding of $D^2$ into $B^4$ which is still not quite what one needs but is close to what one needs to prove that $K$ is slice.

Comment: Aha your comment about composition with diffeomorphism makes the problem clear! Thank you.

Comment: So how exactly does taking the cone force the boundary to be an embedded copy of $K$ and not just the random knot $f(K)$. Is it a general fact that by taking a suffiently small neighbourhood of the vertex of the cone one can force its intersection with a ball containing the vertex point to be $K$?

Comment: Well, I'll agree that some things about that proof do seem to be extraneous. But let me suggest that trying to understand the further issues of that proof is perhaps more appropriate for another question, rather than a discussion here in the comments.